# Python - converting a list of strings into a nested list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, nested

Without importing any modules, I was wondering if it is possible to convert a list of strings into a nested list of strings. A list of strings example would be:

```
['"Hello", "Greetings", "Welcome", "Hi"\n', '"Bye", "Farewell", "Seeya", "Later"\n']
```

A following sample output would be something like (notice I want to get rid of the escape sequence, '\n', as it indicates rows):

```
[["Hello", "Greetings", "Welcome", "Hi"], ["Bye", "Farewell", "Seeya", "Later"]]
```

That said, is there any way I could make this conversion using possible built-in functions like .split() or .strip()?

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Do you have control over how the first list is generated?  What is the broader problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm not sure how you got the data in this state, is this a scrape from a website or something?

Comment: @wflynny you beat me to it. I have recently discovered http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: It looks like you should be using the csv module to parse csv data, but instead you're just reading in lines?

Comment: It clearly looks like OP did a `s = file.read(); s.split(<delimiter>)` instead of iterating through the file or splitting on `'\n'`.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, it sure is. In fact, it uses the two methods you highlight in your post.

```
test = ['"Hello", "Greetings", "Welcome", "Hi"\n', '"Bye", "Farewell", "Seeya", "Later"\n']
sub_lists = [[sub_element.strip('\n') for sub_element in element.split(',')] for element in test]
print(sub_lists)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
def batched(input):
    batch = []
    for item in input:
        if item[-1] == '\n':
           batch.append(item[:-1])
           yield batch
        else:
           batch.append(item)
    if len(batch) > 0:
        yield batch

batched_data = list(batched(['"Hello", "Greetings", "Welcome", "Hi"\n', '"Bye", "Farewell", "Seeya", "Later"\n']))
```